# old Ios App Icon Is availlabe even after changing

Tags: ios, xcode, xcasset

I have an app where I recently replaced the app icons, I removed all of the old assets from everywhere in the project.i removed cache and also uninstalled the app from mobile. After installing and running I am getting the deleted App Icon again in the App

Comment: Try once quitting the Xcode and also removing the Derived Data.

Comment: Remove old icon from workspace and also check AppIcon file has not old app icon in it.

Comment: Did you changed the build number ? I won't be surprised if iOS devices have some cache management

Comment: this issue faced on appicon or project  target's icon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely delete the `bin`and `obj` folders in your project folders (all projects from solution).

This might help on top of what you've already tried.

Other possibility is, you have forgotten a resource ;)

Often times, the problem is between the keyboard and the chair.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :

Use **"Build > Clean all Targets"** and then build and run. Xcode doesn't always see that images have been updated, and leaves them out of incremental builds. Cleaning before building makes Xcode build the app file from scratch, and will pick up any images it's failing to get

Answer (score -1):

**Clean and build** your project.most of the case it works. :)